# Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(10792, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, kaggle

Hey I am using Jupitor Notebook and doing machine learning.
I wrote this code but getting this error and I dont know what is the error.
This is my code for reference:

```
f`rom sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

imp = IterativeImputer(random_state=42)

date = pd.Timestamp('2200-01-01')

for col in combi:
    if combi[col].dtype=="object":
        combi[col].fillna("not listed", inplace=True)
    if combi[col].dtype=="int":
        #X[col].fillna(X[col].mode()[0], inplace=True)
        combi[col].fillna(combi[col].mean(), inplace=True)
        #combi[col] = combi[col].astype.int()
    if combi[col].dtype=='float':
       #X[col].fillna(X[col].mean(), inplace=True)
       combi[col] = imp.fit_transform(combi[col].values.reshape(-1,1))
    if combi[col].dtype=="datetime64[ns]":
        combi[col].fillna(date, inplace=True)
combi`
```

Solution of the problem

Comment: What is combi? You are using col both as element within combi and as an index to select an element of combi.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `for` loops work in Python.

```
for col in combi:
    if combi[col].dtype=="object":
        # ...
```

`col` isn't an index into the collection you're iterating over (`combi`), it *is* the dereferenced element itself. Change all instances of `combi[col]` inside your `for` loop to `col` to correct. Example:

```
for col in combi:
    if col.dtype=="object":
```

You didn't post all of your code so it's unclear if this will resolved the problem you're seeing, but it is certainly a step in the right direction.

Comment: I didnot work I will add my whole code